# Import Excel Files in to .net is not working after certain period in Production

Tags: asp.net

I have been developed code to import excel sheet data in to grid, using c#.
It's working fine in Local , when it comes to production, after certain period of time it's giving an error saying `Unspecified error`. If I reset the IIS server, it gets resolved. Can any one suggest permanent solution for the same?

Sample code to open Excel:

```
fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                    fuExcel.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + fileLocation + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    DataTable dtFromExcel = new DataTable();
                    DataTable dtBarcodeDetails = new DataTable();
                    string Sheet = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SheetName"].ToString();
                    using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {   
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + Sheet + "$]", excelConnection);
                        excelConnection.Open();
                        OleDbDataReader dReader;
                        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        dtFromExcel.Load(dReader);
                        excelConnection.Close();
                    }
```

Config code:

```
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
        <identity impersonate="false"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="43200"/>
    </system.web>
```

Comment: have you excel driver installed on your server?

Comment: You will need to find another way to read Excel files on the server, see point 4 under "Overview" [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255): "not intended to be used from asp.net"

Comment: i am not using ADE, i am using Jet.OLEDB, you can see in code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if Exceptions get raised in your Excel processing, your connection will be disposed. 
But I am not sure it will be closed.
Does it change something if you try something like this ?

```
using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + Sheet + "$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtFromExcel.Load(dReader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (excelConnection != null && excelConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            excelConnection.Close();
        OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: No, it doesn't helping my cause

Comment: @user2060493 : edited my answer, see the ReleaseObjectPool() in the finally clause